How to move an interface to an upstream package in PHP
Suppose that in a PHP library package I have this:
namespace Upstream {

  class Thing {
  }

}

And in another library package, which depends on Upstream, I have this:
namespace Library {

  interface NewInterface {}

  class Thing extends \Upstream\Thing {
    public function newMethod(NewInterface $parameter): self {
      return $this;
    }
  }

}

I want to move newMethod() and NewInterface to the Upstream package.
Is there a way to do that without breaking compatibility? In other words, is there way to do it safely in a semver minor release?

Adding the interface to the upstream shouldn't have any BC issues since it is in its own namespace, but removing the interface from the downstream could be a BC break for consumers. You could have the downstream interface extend the upstream one though, and then move all of the contents from the downstream into the upstream, as long as none of those contents references the downstream namespace. Adding newMethod to upstream would require a signature change, however, so that's probably a big BC issue.
